# Twitter bootstrap background behind the navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with a navbar-wrapper class which makes it floating at the top center of the browser. I'd like to have a rectangle zone behind it filled with blue color. How should I do it?

Consider this page http://lowcoupling.com/post/59130887987/defining-project-plans-and-gantt-charts-in-eclipse

I'd like to add a blue filled area before body and behind the navbar.

**UPDATE**
I have managed to do something similar to what I wanted by adding an empty jumbotron at the beginning of the body and by setting

```
.jumbotron{
    margin-top:-90px;
    background-color:rgb(20,7,91);
}
```

The problem is that it has rounded corner and the two top corners leave an annoying white space as you can see http://lowcoupling.com/post/59130887987/defining-project-plans-and-gantt-charts-in-eclipse

Any idea on how to work around it?

**UPDATE**
It was easy

```
.jumbotron{
    margin-top:-90px;
    background-color:rgb(20,7,91);
    border-radius:0px;
}
```

Comment: How are we suppose to know? You need to provide us with some code. Without it, we are unable to help you.

Comment: excuse me, I have updated the question

Comment: No need to get defensive, I was just telling you that if you expect any kind of help, the least you can do is provide us with some code.

Comment: Is not enought override the background style of the wrapper (v. g. .navbar-container) ?

Answer (score 0):

assuming your navbar-wrapper class is 'navbar-wrapper'

```
.navbar-wrapper {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

or, if like the example you link to

```
.navbar {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea for this might be using z-index. You said, before the body and behind the navbar.

Try this:

`body {

 // write body font, font-size, color etc

}`

Then you can use z-index to make the navbar float over it (But remember, each element always floats over the body, so you don't need this; but still if you want to use it)

`.navbar {

 z-index: 2; // 2 to make sure, that others stay under it always
 background-color: #hexforblue;

 padding: 5px 10px; // to make it a rect.

 }`

After using this, the navbar will have a rectangular div floating behind.

**Note:** This will be the background for whole of the div, not for just a small portion of it.